# Execute PHP file with argument using cron job

Tags: php, curl, cron, cron-task

I have a PHP with mySQL website just setup recently and it needs to have a cron task running regularly in order to create records.

The link is like

> www.website.com/index.php/task/cron/api_number

If placing this link to a web browser then run, it works and records can be created.

However, after setting up Cron job likes

```
/usr/bin/php public_html/index.php/task/cron/api_number
```

it didn't work and the error was like

```
Status: 404 Not Found
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.5.35
Content-type: text/html

No input file specified.
```

I followed someone's Stackoverflow guide and tried curl, with both public link and relative link but not working.

I can understand that `No input file specified.` means the file is not actually existing but any suggestions of what I could do?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use your real path to this file, e.g:

```
/usr/bin/php /path/to/your/php/file/
```

Or if you just want to trigger an URL, you could do:

```
wget http://www.website.com/index.php/task/cron/api_number
```

(no need for php if you trigger URL, just call an URL like a web browser)